# AutofacInstanceContext.Current is null and I don't get why

Tags: c#, wcf, autofac, mediatr

I'm working on a WCF project in which I'm using Autofac as IoC container and MediatR as a mediator to execute my requests & commands.

The "base" implementation of the WCF contract takes an instance of `IMediator` as a dependency to delegate the work associated with each request to the associated handler. I also have several decorators I stack up the base implementation for things like authorization and error handling.

As specified in [this page of Autofac documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/wcf.html#using-decorators-with-services), the use of a `MultitenantServiceImplementationDataProvider` is necessary in order to satisfy WCF internals when you use decorators on the service implementation. Nothing more multitenant-related is needed, so it just consists of:

```cs
AutofacServiceHostFactory.ServiceImplementationDataProvider = new MultitenantServiceImplementationDataProvider();
```

Also, in the `.svc` I specified the qualified name of the interface since it's supported by Autofac and I have decorators on top on my base implementation.

Now, on to MediatR.
MediatR uses service location to instantiate the appropriate handlers when it is given a request. More specifically, it relies on [CSL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator/).

Not a problem, since Autofac provides a [bridge to support CSL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator/).
The "tricky" part relies in the fact that my handlers take `DbContext` as dependencies, and I want them disposed by Autofac after each WCF request.
So the `AutofacServiceLocator` has to be given the scope that is created for the specific request, since the root scope is not disposed and neither would be the `DbContext` instances.

Autofac got you covered with the `AutofacInstanceContext.Current` static property which is the equivalent of the `AutofacDependencyResolver.RequestLifetimeScope` in ASP.NET MVC.
So far so good, here's how I registered the `ServiceLocatorProvider` the `Mediator` class takes a depedency on:

```cs
builder
    .Register(x => new ServiceLocatorProvider(() => new AutofacServiceLocator(AutofacInstanceContext.Current.OperationLifetime)))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

It works as expected on my development box but I get a `NullReferenceException` on the staging environment and I don't really know where to look for - GoogleBing didn't give relevant results.

Only things that differ from both environments:

- HTTP on my box vs HTTPS on the staging env.
- `debug`attribute on `<system.web>` element was set to false on staging env.

And that's about it...
.NET frameworks as the same, 4.5.2.

Anyone has an idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by changing:

```
builder
    .Register(x => new ServiceLocatorProvider(() => new AutofacServiceLocator(AutofacInstanceContext.Current.OperationLifetime)))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

with

```
builder
    .Register(x => 
    {
        var serviceLocator = new AutofacServiceLocator(AutofacInstanceContext.Current.OperationLifetime);
        return new ServiceLocatorProvider(() => serviceLocator);
    }
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

I wouldn't be able to tell you exactly why it didn't work, but I guess that by the time the lambda expression `() => new AutofacServiceLocator(AutofacInstanceContext.Current.OperationLifetime)` was executed internally by MediatR, it was too late and the current operation context was disposed of or released.

Any insight would still be greatly appreciated!

Comment: which version of MediatR are you using? It has moved away from Common Service Locator in favor of factory method delegates  https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/commit/82ce595fcd5d265862bf80127fee932902c3d8cd

Comment: I'm using the latest stable version, 1.0.0. Jimmy stated he won't make 2.0 stable until .NET Core is stable if I'm not mistaken. Anyway, I don't think this would change much regarding my issue